# Running getblocktemplate on a remote node or a local node without syncing

Tags: bitcoin, json-rpc, mining, bitcoind

Hi I've been trying to learn more about Bitcoin mining and was reading about the getblocktemplate protocol. I came across this [page](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/getblocktemplate.html).  At the bottom, it has this example which would be useful for playing around with:

`curl --user myusername --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "getblocktemplate", "params": [{"rules": ["segwit"]}] }' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:8332/`

However, that example assumes you have a local bitcoind server running, which I don't.  The issue is, pulling down the blockchain takes about a week or more, plus all the space it takes up.

Does there exist a way to run getblocktemplate either locally or some playground server that has the current blockchain?  Or must I download the entire blockchain to play around with this protocol on the real-world blockchain?

Answer (score -1):

Running a node of your own is important to using Bitcoin in any secure capacity, and definitely to mine.

You can reduce disk usage by enabling pruning (prune=1000 in bitcoin.conf for a 1 GB storage cap). If you have a lot of memory, you can also set dbcache=10000 to let it use up to 10 GB RAM for caching and thereby accelerate the sync (you can remove this later).

Another option for experimentation would be to run a testnet node. Testnet not only has a smaller blockchain, but also a much lower mining difficulty so you can also see results of mining. Depending on your need, you might be able to get away with "regtest", a local-only/per-user test network with a zero difficulty (instant mining - no need to find a proof-of-work hash).